# Приоритеты операций в языке Си

Tags: c, инкремент

Допустим имеется следующий фрагмент:

```
int a = 0; --a ? --a : ++a;
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, преждче чем приведется в действие тернарная операция, в порядке приоритета, справа налево инкрементируется переменная, затем она декремнтируется, затем снова декрементируется, вычислится условный переход и вернется левое выражение? Если нет, то как же работает приоритет?
И что делать в случае если

```
a = ++c + ++c;
```

Или

```
a= c++ + ++c;
```

Как разбирать порядки выполнения в соответствии с таблицей приоритетов? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Стандартная ситуация [неопределенного поведения {undefined behaviour}](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) лучше избегать таких ситуаций.

Comment: @Yaroslav, не уверен, что здесь в первом случае UB... хотя инстинкты и говорят, что скорей всего оно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю,

Нет.

```
int a = 0; 
--a? --a : ++a;
```

1. `--a` в `--a?`, значение `а` стало `-1`, в булевском смысле - `true`
2. `--a` - первый операнд, второй операнд не вычисляется, значение `а` стало `-2`
3. результат: значение `а` - `-2`

Comment: Объясните порядок выполнения и расстановки приоритета

Comment: Конечно! Пожалуйста! Пожалуйста, объясните =)

Comment: @AyratArifullin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx